# fire a query using elastic search without "id" key

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to search whether a value for particular key exist or not in the node.

```
{
  "_index": "some_index",
  "_type": "some_type",
  "_id": "some_id",
  "_version": ver,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "timestamp", 
    "fragments": ["1234", "5678", "8912"]
  }
}
```

In this case, what will be the query in java if I want to find whether **fragment** `5678` is present, with an ouput as: `5678 exist`?

Comment: running a curl command works ie :
`curl -XGET "http://localhost:port/index/type/_search/exists?q<fragment_value>"`

where in my case fragment value is **5678**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fragment = "xyz"
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(_index)
           .setTypes(_type)
           .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fragments", fragment))
           .execute().actionGet();
```

Worked in my case.